# Gravar data com milésimos de segundos

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma aplicação no qual dois usuários podem atualizar um item no banco de dados, no entanto fiquei pensando na seguinte situação:

Se eles clicarem para sincronizar no mesmo instante, incluindo hora/minutos/segundos pode subscrever a atualização um do outro ou ocorreria algum problema(isso na minha cabeça).

Para resolver isso pensei em usar milésimos de segundos, que no caso a probabilidade seria menos ainda, porém como dizem, um raio não cai no mesmo lugar, mas vai que cai. No momento estou usando desta forma para obter o horário atual da sincronização:

```
$date_sync = time();
$date_sync = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $date_sync);
```

Sei que existem diversas maneiras no qual posso resolver esse problema, porém não sei muito bem qual seria a mais viável. Alguém poderia me dar uma sugestão?!

Comment: Na verdade é o contrário, raios tem tendência a cair sempre no mesmo lugar (aconteceu com a sogra de um amigo nosso inclusive). A autonumeração do DB serve para evitar este tipo de coisa, você pode conjugar o tempo e o ID gerado, (ou usar só o ID) para identificação única. Se é alteração no mesmo ítem do DB, você precisa de algum outro tipo de controle (não deletar o registro nem gravar por cima, e sim acrescentar um novo que substitua o anterior)

Comment: Pelo fato do raio ir pelo caminho de menor resistência, tende a ser repetitivo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6azrJq6V5Q - apesar de fora do problema do DB, acho que a analogia vale pra qq coisa que dependa de "sorte" :)

Comment: @Bacco achei eu fizesse de uma forma assim, simplificaria minha situação. heuhe. Acho que vou criar outra tabela então para controle.